# Looking for a word that implies another person's presumed experience

Tags: single-word-requests

When there is a decision that needs to be made between you and another person. It would be good if it has connotations of a presumed expertise. For example, if you and another person were looking for an answer to a complex problem, either party could make the decision but you believe their decision would be best. Something like "I defer to you for this decision", or "I concede the decision to you". Neither of the words are what I believe I'm looking for.

Comment: Can you give a context relevant sentence with a blank for the word you want? Also why don't defer or concede work?

Comment: The specific context for which I need the word is exactly what I described in the question's two examples. Defer and concede don't work because they don't convey any purpose for deferring or conceding the decision. @JohnFeltz 's comment seems to fit nicely. Rather than simply deferring to someone else, I am also offering a reason why. I had hoped to find a single word for this, but "I defer to your expertise on the matter" will certainly suffice.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80828/discussion-on-question-by-jack-looking-for-a-word-that-implies-another-persons).

Answer (score 3):

You can use "entrust"

"I entrust this decision to you."

Both meaning you trust the other person to make the decision* (see note below), and also are placing the responsibility for making the decision in the hands of that person.

> 1. To give over (something) to another for care, protection, or performance
>     [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/entrust)

*Actually I may have been wrong about the first point. The proposition that you trust the other person is implied, not necessary, when entrusting a task to another.

This is clarified by this usage note in Collins English Dictionary:

> Usage: It is usually considered incorrect to talk about entrusting
>   someone to do something: the army cannot be trusted (not entrusted) to
>   carry out orders
>  [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/entrust)